Mint leaves have lots of small yellowing dots, what is it?
My mint has been growing since the beginning of spring and it has been growing leaves that start a vibrant green but dull to a much lighter green with yellowed dots all around it.
I am mostly growing plants to learn what works and what doesn't so I could be doing something wrong with them or I could be ignorant to what the plant needs. I know some of the problems could be being too hot, having too much sun, or being underwatered since I am in the lower mid-country of South Carolina or it could be something different like the wrong soil (pH, mineral content, etc.). I have no clue how to test soil and I need help understanding what could be wrong. The plant is growing in a standing box that has basil and a small blackberry plant in it, however, I pruned back the plant before posting this so I can't really show a whole plant picture.
Issue Leaf

Young Leaves


Can you post you images here as part of your question, please?  I've upvoted your good question; that should give you some rep, which hopefully will be enough to add images (I'm not sure if that will be enough though... I don't recall at the moment).

Can you add a photo of the whole plant please and say whether its growing in a pot or in open ground

Hey, firstly you need to check below the leaves if there might be any insects underneath of the leaves if yes, tell me we can solve the issue.

I looked at the bases and at the soil and didn't see any bugs at the moment. We have a few anoles that sit near the planter box which hunts any bug that is there if that might help at all, but there were no bugs.

"The plant is growing in a standing box that has basil and a small blackberry plant in it" Wait, you mean those have absolutely zero damage? The answer is clear - aliens.
